# javascript: Checking if user agent is on desktop device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, user-agent

I'm looking all over the web and still can't find a pretty decent way to check if a browser is used on a desktop computer or on tablet/mobile.

Consider the next issue, there are touch devices which are desktop (desktop surface).
Eventually what im trying to achieve is to separate between the next two:
1. Touch devices that have orientation switching enabled
2. Touch devices that are actually desktop ones

**Is there any recommended way to check this?**

Also, I tried the next 3rd party WURFL.io but i found 2 issues with that:
It gives you a too-simple result (which encapsulates all the decisions inside) and it basically not working well when emulating a mobile device on chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
  dosomething();
} else {
   dosomething(); //this is the browser
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some improved way based on previous answer: returns boolean instead of array.

```
let isMobile = Boolean(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)?.length)
```